# Burn multiple playlists to CD from iTunes

Tags: itunes

By default, I am fairly certain iTunes does not support this .... but is there a way to burn multiple playlists to one CD? Client does not want to dump playlists into one giant one then burn..he wishes to have the  playlists in their original hierarchy one one CD ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes (9 in this case) doesn't support this, but I have a workaround:

1. Create a Burn Folder ( File -> New Burn Folder ) on your desktop.
2. Create folders within the Burn Folder that reflect the names of your playlists
3. Drag items from iTunes playlist to the corresponding folder in the Burn Folder...
4. Then select "Burn" from the Burn folder Finder window to get it to CD

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes create a blank playlist. Open each playlist you wish to burn one at a time, select the entire song list and move it to the blank playlist. You can do this as many times as you wish to the 750 MB capacity limit of a blank CD. Go to *Burn to Disc*.

If you convert your files to MP3 beforehand, you can store many more songs on one CD.